# how to get admin email page from facebook graph API

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hello i'm trying to figure out how to get the admin page email with facebook graph API.
 is there any option to get this data with the API ? or an alternative way to get this data without facebook graph API.

thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You can not get the personal email addresses of people that are admins for arbitrary Facebook pages. The most you can get is the `emails` field for the page – that will show all email addresses they might have entered in the page’s About section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page) endpoint there is the `emails` field:

> The emails listed in the About section of a Page

For an [App](https://developers.prod.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application) there are two fields: `contact_email` and `user_support_email`:

> Email address users can use to contact developers

and

> Main contact email for this app where people can receive support

The policy forbids using any other mechanism but the API to retrieve information from Facebook (e.g. scraping is not allowed).